# Find why a filter expression failed to evaluate in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, rdl

In Visual Studio 2013, I am attempting to preview a report pulled straight from source control.  The preview is failing with the error message returned is simply "Failed to evaluate the FilterExpression of the Tablix '*table_name*'".  Is there some place I can look to get further details on the failure, some explanation of what part of the filter failed?

Also to note, I've had a co-worker confirm it is functioning in Visual Studio 2012.  So in particular, I'm looking for where it would tell me what I'm using in the filter section that has been invalidated between 2012 to 2013.  Though anywhere I can find more details than 'filter failed' is likely to be helpful.

Comment: Did you try the SSRS logs?

Comment: Checking the execution log on the report server only shows reports I've ran from the dev environment, not reports I previewed.  Is their a seperate place for preview logs?

Comment: In the dev environment, I usually find a more detailed message in the errors window.  On my box, the logs from doing Preview can be found here (YMMV):  C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Projects\SSRS Logs\SSRS-Prod\SSRS-Prod\Rpt01.   And there are other folders besides "Rpt01", presumably each for a different report?   Maybe this will help?:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6bf2a4c9-f652-4c99-972b-75ba9d9447c2/locate-ssrs-log-files   Or just search your C: drive for files with "ReportServerService" in the name.

Comment: Searching doesn't return anything.  I've also looked in the locations mentioned in the link.  Is there perhaps a setting somewhere that says to either log or not in preview?

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the same issue and it was caused by a cached .data file. During development, Visual Studio will cache the data for the file and save it as [Report Name].rdl.data in the same folder as the .rdl file itself. If you make a change such as adding a new field, you may need to delete this .data file before you can preview the report again.